# ssh key issue with mac and git, pushing from wrong account

Tags: git, macos, ssh

I have purchased a new laptop that had git already setup with my coworkers account.

I deleted the 2 key files in the ssh directory and generated new ones. I then copied over the pub key and added to my beanstalk repo ssh key list. However whenever i pushed a commit, it seems to still be pushing under his account.

I am so very lost and am new to macs. I did "ssh -v gt@beanstalkapp.com" and it seems to be pointing to the newly generated keys.

Any help is appreciated, i am not really sure what to try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **git config --list** to see the settings for git, then update those values that aren't what you want.

> git config --list

For example:

> git config --global user.name "Your Name"

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup

Answer (score 1):

Check the **.gitconfig** file, change the `[user]` settings there to point to your account

```
[user]
    email = johndoe@example.com
    name = John Doe
```